# ¿Como puedo introducir un elemento dentro de otro con Vuejs?

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo colocar un elementos dentro de otro elemento, creado por la función `component` de Vuejs?
Tengo mi código creado con el template de Vuejs, pero quiero crear elementos dentro de otros elementos, pero me da error y no muestra nada.
Digamos quiero poder hacer algo asi:

```
<div id="app">
<my-element id="element" v-for="data in 1000">
         <my-child id="child">{{ data }}</my-child>
</my-element>
</div>
```

Y este es mi script de Vuejs:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  componentes: {
    my-element: {
      props: {
        id: ''
      },
      template: '<div class="content"></div>'
    },
    my-child: {
      props: {
        id: ''
      },
    template: '<div class="child"></div>
    }
  }
});
```

La pagina oficial de este template esta [aquí](https://Vuejs.org), esta basado en javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recuerda siempre revisar la documentación oficial, aquí te dejo algo que puede serte de utilidad.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots

Un ***scoped slot*** es un tipo especial de slot que funciona como un template reutilizable (al cual se le puede pasar data) en lugar de ***already-rendered-elements***. En un componente hijo, puedes pasar data dentro de un slot como si pasarás props a un componente:

```
<div class="child">
  <slot text="hello from child"></slot>
</div>
```

En el componente padre, debe exisitr un elemento `<template>` con un atributo especial ***slot-scope***, indicando que es una plantilla para un ***scoped slot***. El valor del slot-scope se usará como nombre de una variable temporal que contiene el objeto props pasado del componente hijo:

```
<div class="parent">
  <child>
    <template slot-scope="props">
      <span>hello from parent</span>
      <span>{{ props.text }}</span>
    </template>
  </child>
</div>
```

Una vez compilado se verá así:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>hello from parent</span>
    <span>hello from child</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`my-child` debe de ir dentro de `my-element`

```
components: {
  'my-element': {
    props: {
      id: ''
    },
    template: '<div class="content"></div>',
    components: {
      'my-child': { ....
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres utilizar slot, recomiendo que utilices un archivo html como template y no la etiqueta template yo tuve ese problema.

```
template: require('./companies.html'),
props:{
}...
```